# Radio button does not get checked

Tags: php, html, radio-button

I want to set a radio button checked if it has a value, my code generates following output:

```
<input id="radio2" type="radio" checked="checked" value="2" name="radio">
```

But for some strange reason, it does not set the radio button checked. I can see that the radio is checked for a very short time when the page is loading but disappears quickly.

[image]
Here's the screenshot from the Firebug, why does it display `checked: false` in the doom when it is `checked="checked"` in the source? What's causing that?

The `checked="checked"` is added in the source with PHP (jQuery is not used for it).

Comment: Please provide your full html code along with php.

Comment: Do you habe more than one radio buttons with the name `radio`? Only one of them can be checked. Do you have a Javascript running wich can change the state of your fields?

Comment: This one is working ,i have tried this code what you have provided

Comment: Its woking fine for
<input id="radio2" type="radio" checked="checked" value="2" name="radio">

Answer (score 0):

This is the normal way for making a radio button checked. please provide full code

```
<input type="radio" name="radio1"  value="2" checked="checked" />
```

Comment: Even the user1355300 knows that its like that. But the question is why its not checking the radio box then? Care to answer Angel

Answer (score 0):

Your code is right but
I think another javascript was change your radio button.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<input id="radio2" type="radio" value="2" name="radio" checked>
```